# Google Sheet script that changes automatically based on the day?

Tags: button, google-sheets

Basically I created a script in google sheets that was then added to a button so that I could click the button and count the number of calls I make throughout the day. Button is assigned to a specific cell (i.e. A1). Is is possible to re-write the script so that each day the script knows to stay in the same Column (A), but go to the next row (A2) so that I can track my daily calls without having to reassign the script to a specific cell each day?

Comment: Could you add the code attached to your button and what is in column A? Or share you spreadsheet. It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @EdNelson https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ljdk10n7WsRb7ERe-Io5DUPrNwQBKpkTD2dPY-NtHHU/edit#gid=0

Comment: See the spreadsheet... code is on there as well. looking to have: 1) the button track different types of calls through the day 2) i.e. tomorrow for exmaple, i want to track calls using the same button as well but would love to script to automatically know to go to the next cell that corresponds to the next day

Comment: You need to share the spreadsheet and post the shared link.

Comment: @EdNelson you should be good to go! my apologies

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but the attached copy of your spreadsheet finds the current date and then runs your code based on the current date when the button is clicked. I hope this is what you want. If not, please explain further.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2CAhLcMuyECfx3zrUcRvSGOP0nNpBQRkMg-1JO4kys/edit?usp=sharing
```